# How to create Flux from Mono

Tags: java, java-stream, spring-webflux

I have a Mono A. The Object A contains two lists. I want to create direct two Flux. Is this possible without block()?

```
Mono<A> a = ... ;

Flux<AList1> a1 =  Flux.fromIterable(a.block().getList1());
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use Mono.flatMapMany() method:

```
    Flux flux1 = mono.map(A::getList1).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
    Flux flux2 = mono.map(A::getList2).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```