# How to get Flux<Bar> from Mono<JSONObject> in Spring Reactor API?

Tags: java-8, java-stream, project-reactor

I have `Mono<JSONObject> mono` coming from API service with json response that looks like:

```
{  
  "total": 45,
  "results": [{"age": 23, "color": "blue"}, {"age": 34, "color": "orange"}]
}
```

and

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
```

documented in this [link](http://javadox.com/net.minidev/json-smart/1.2/net/minidev/json/JSONObject.html)

Each element of results array in json response maps to Bar object. I want to get

```
Flux<Bar> bars
```

from above mono.

I also want to get

`int total` from above mono.

How can I achieve this?  I am lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you a flux of JSONObject corresponding to the Bar class:

```
Flux<JSONObject> barsAsJsonObject = mono.flatMap(jsonObject -> jsonObject.get("results"))
        .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
```

Since `jsonObject.get("results")` gives a JSONArray which extends ArrayList, we can use the `Mono.flatMapMany()` to create a flux out of it.
Refer [this](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190668/how-to-create-flux-from-mono).

After this you can map the JSON objects to the Bar objects as follows, which will give you a Flux of Bar:

```
barsAsJsonObject.map( barAsJson -> {
//create Bar object here
})
```

Apply the [count](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#count--) operator to the flux to get the count of Bar objects.

Hope, that answers your question.

Comment: I want to get total, not count.

Comment: @ace you can extract the total in the similar way, by using the key "total" and getting it from the jsonObject itself.