# How to get Flux out of list that is inside Mono?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-mongodb

I've got a Mono with an object that contains a list. I need to get that list out of  Mono and put it inside Flux.

```
public Flux<Message> getMessages(String id) {
        return chatDAO.findById(id);
}
```

That `findById` method takes an id of a chat and returns `Mono<Chat>` where `Chat` has a list of messages. I want to take that list of messages and convert it into `Flux<Messages>`

Comment: Another SO topic that covers the question on a high-level could found here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49190668/how-to-create-flux-from-mono

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use a combination of [Mono#flatMapMany](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#flatMapMany-java.util.function.Function-) and [Flux#fromIterable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-) methods in the following way

```
public Flux<Message> getMessages(String id) {
    return chatDAO.findById(id)
                  .map(Chat::getMessages) //assumes that you have getter for your messages
                  .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
}
```